# How to check if an array contains exactly specific items independent of their order in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Every document has a users array. I want to check in db if a document has in its users array the value -> `['123','456']` OR `['456','123']`, the order doesn't matter but I need that THESE AND ONLY THESE values are present in users array.

I'm basically looking for something like `set(users.array) == set(456, 123)`

I tried using `$in` operator but it is not working properly because it gives "true" if just one of these exists, and `$all` as I have seen don't check if these are the only values present.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using $in operator but it is not working properly because it gives "true" if just one of these exists,and $all as I have seen dont check if these are the only values present

Comment: Using `$all` is a good thought. You could additionally use `$size` and check that the array sizes are equal. Depending on how you need to handle duplicates though, that could get tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to test 2 things:

- the array contains all of the desired elements
- the array does not contain any undesired elements

The [$all](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all) query operator handles the first test. `{$all: ["123","456"]}`

For the second test, you can use then [$nin](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/#-nin) operator, `{$nin: ["123","456"]}`  Since that tests the entire array at once, by itself it will only match documents that don't contain the desired values.

Using the [$elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator to apply the `$nin` test to each element separately
matches unwanted documents. `{$elemMatch:{$nin: ["123","456"}}`

Invert the `$eleMatch` using [$not](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/not/#-not) to eliminate the undesired documents.

Putting that all together:

```
{$and: [
    {key: {$all: ["123","456"]}},
    {key: {$not: {$elemMatch: {$nin: {"123","456"}}}}}
]}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EivgFa7iFa5)

Comment: I think you missed the `$not`

Comment: yes, good eye, fixed

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!!!! WOW IT WORKED AT FIRST...it helped A LOT (by the way anyone seeing this `{$nin: {"123","456"}}` is `{$nin: ["123","456"]}` ....just a little typo nothing to worry about ...the answer keeps awesome!!!! have a nice day